# UIActionSheet in iOS8 retains views

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactionsheet, ios8.1

I'm using UIActionSheet in iOS8(my app needs to support iOS7) but it looks like under iOS8, UIActionSheet retains the view! I made a simple app where I have two view controllers in a navigation view controller, ViewController1 and ViewController2.

ViewController2 presents an action sheet. In my delegate, which is the view controller itself, I dismiss the view controller.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

What I am observing is that in iOS8.1, this action sheet somehow retains the view it is presented in. In iOS 7.1, this works fine.

Has anyone run into this, or have any workarounds? I created https://github.com/brightredchilli/iOS8-actionsheet-tests as a proof of concept.

Comment: UIActionSheet is deprecated as of iOS 8.0. Use UIAlertController instead.

Comment: @gagarwal The app supports iOS 7. There is no reason to switch to `UIAlertController` in such a case.

Comment: Using UIActionSheet on iOS 8.0 may have side effects, like it won't rotate to PortraitUpsideDown. Based on the iOS version launch UIActionSheet/UIAlertController. This is recommended as in future iOS updates UIActionSheet may be completely gone and your existing app starts crashing.

Comment: try to release your UIActionSheet after every use

Comment: @gagarwal, this does not work if you need to support both ios7 and ios8. I'm still looking for an answer to this question, although what I have done temporarily is to wrap UIActionSheet, using UIAlertController for ios8+ and UIActionSheet for everything below that.

Comment: I have this issue to.  It breaks one of my apps.  This is infuriating.  Apple messed up ios 8 so bad that I'm just about done with ios development.  It's that awful.  I've never had to code so many workarounds for a bad sdk.